# Twitter Bootstrap - Button not rendering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Welcome to my garage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" >
      <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" >MyGarage</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse" >
            Rooms
          </button>

        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Garage</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Toilet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <h1> List of posts (yet ;) ) </h1>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="http://localhost/4dd1cti0n/index.php/add_post">Add Post</a> 
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Can someone explain why the  tag was not rendered in firefox? I'm playing with twitter bootstrap.

What I wanted was to have a drop-down button called "Rooms" in the nav-bar which drops down "Garage" and "Toilet"

Thankyou

Comment: Can you show us some css? maybe post a working demo too?

Comment: your mark is not proper , your head tag not completed properly , there  are so many mistakes

Answer (score 0):

replace this markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to my garage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" >
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" >MyGarage</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse" >
                    Rooms
                </button>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Garage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Toilet</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <h1> List of posts (yet ;) ) </h1>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <a href="http://localhost/4dd1cti0n/index.php/add_post">Add Post</a> 
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```